# How to Capitalized each first letter for a Sentence in Flutter...?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, letter

I want to capitalize each first letter from a sentence for Flutter..??

**This is a capitalized sentence**
I'm expecting from **This Is A Capitalized Sentence**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
extension StringExtension on String {
  String capitalizeByWord() {
    if (trim().isEmpty) {
      return '';
    }
    return split(' ')
        .map((element) =>
            "${element[0].toUpperCase()}${element.substring(1).toLowerCase()}")
        .join(" ");
  }
}
```

Use extension like this. So that you can use `capitalizeByWord` on any String to convert it.

```
void main() async {
  var data = 'this is a capitalized sentence';
  print(data.capitalizeByWord()); // This prints the result 'This Is A Capitalized Sentence'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
extension StringExtension on String {
    String capitalize() {
      return "${this[0].toUpperCase()}${this.substring(1).toLowerCase()}";
    }
}
```

So you can just call your extension like this:

```
import "string_extension.dart";

var someCapitalizedString = "someString".capitalize();
```

Comment: this is not work..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a well tested method that I made:

```
extension StringExtension on String {
```

/// Capitalize the first letter of each word in a string
///
/// `dart /// String example = "hello world".capitalizeAllWordsFirstLetter(); // Hello World ///` 
String capitalizeAllWordsFirstLetter() {
String lowerCasedString = toLowerCase();
String stringWithoutExtraSpaces = lowerCasedString.trim();

```
if (stringWithoutExtraSpaces.isEmpty) {
  return "";
}
if (stringWithoutExtraSpaces.length == 1) {
  return stringWithoutExtraSpaces.toUpperCase();
}

List<String> stringWordsList = stringWithoutExtraSpaces.split(" ");
List<String> capitalizedWordsFirstLetter = stringWordsList
    .map(
      (word) {
        if (word.trim().isEmpty) return "";
        return word.trim();
      },
    )
    .where(
      (word) => word != "",
    )
    .map(
      (word) {
        if (word.startsWith(RegExp(r'[\n\t\r]'))) {
          return word;
        }
        return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1).toLowerCase();
      },
    )
    .toList();
String finalResult = capitalizedWordsFirstLetter.join(" ");
return finalResult;
}}

 print("this is an example sentence"); // This Is An Example Sentence
```